# SSIS Flat File destination Comma separated after each fixed column value (After Fixed Length of column)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I've spent almost a day to find a solution for this, but so far no luck.

Here is the problem:
In my SSIS Package I'm trying to export data from SQL server table to flat file destination with fixed length option followed by comma.

```
Ex:  Account     Address          Zip
     123456    ,2525 Est dr     ,77077
     563       ,12 we dr        ,75023
```

If you see the above example the Account is 10 character length, and Address is 16 character length.

So I need write like this to a flat file with fixed length followed by comma (in other words comma should come between the columns)

But the in flat file destination of SSIS, I am not able to set both Fixed length and comma delimiter at the same time. Either one is working , but not both.

Please suggests me the options, to get this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an odd schema for a flatfile, but OK.  Set the flatfile to be fixed with.  Then pad the columns with trailing spaces and a comma yourself.  Two methods come to mind.

1. Update your `OLE DB Source`component to use a SQL statement that does the padding for you ..

   ```
   SELECT 
       Account + REPLICATE(' ',10 - LEN(Account)) + ',',
       Address + REPLICATE(' ',16 - LEN(Address)) + ',',
       Zip + REPLICATE(' ',5 - LEN(Zip)) + ','
   FROM MyTable
   ```
2. Use a `Derived Column Transformation` to do a similar thing.

Comment: Thanks Troy, yes i know this is a odd schema :(, but I'm just going as per the requirement.

Comment: Understood.  Sometimes we just have to make it work.  Glad we could get a working solution for you!  :)   Good luck!